# using dt.AsEnumerable().Sum for columns having string/null value

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, sum

I an using following way to get total of a column from a datatable

```
string total = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>("col1")).ToString();
```

This works fine when all the values of col1 are number.

My question is-  lets consider if any one value of col1 is string or null or anything else other than number, the above code will throw error obviously.

Is there any way to check whether the value is number and use '0' instead if value is not number.

I tried -

```
string total = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(x =>  x.Field<decimal>("col1") is int ? x.Field<decimal>("col1") : 0).ToString();
```

but not sure if it the correct way.

Please help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's not a `decimal` but a `string` you would even get a `InvalidCastException` in the [`Field<T>` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So you have to know what type it is.

I assume that `Col1`  can be `null`, `Field<T>` supports nullable types:

```
decimal total = dt.AsEnumerable()
 .Sum(r => r.Field<decimal?>("Col1") ?? 0);
```

or without replacing `null` with `0`:

```
decimal? total = dt.AsEnumerable()
 .Sum(r => r.Field<decimal?>("Col1")); // use total.HasValue and total.Value
```

Presuming `string`, you could use `decimal.TryParse`:

```
decimal d = 0;
decimal total = dt.AsEnumerable()
 .Where(r => decimal.TryParse(r.Field<string>("Col1"), out d))
 .Sum(r => d);
```

If you don't know what type it is you could use `object.ToString`:

```
decimal total = dt.AsEnumerable()
 .Where(r => !r.IsNull("Col1") && decimal.TryParse(r["Col1"].ToString(), out d))
 .Sum(r => d);
```

Apart from that, why do you store the converted number again in a string variable?